# Android ListView inside ExpandableList

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistadapter

Getting visible only one child of Expandable List adapter and other one's partially visible. I am using List view adapter for getting child list and store them in a array list but after a lot of searching and trying with Layout still problem is not resolved so guy's please help me in this scenario!!!!!

Comment: Set the inner `ListView`'s height to something fixed, like `100dp`.

Comment: i have tried this but still it's not working...